# Calling values ​in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I use woocommerce rest api. I can pull all values ​​such as name, price description with get, but I cannot capture category and picture values.The reason is that they are in array. How can I shoot them?
i can share request code;

```
<td><?= $row['categories;']; ?></td>
<td><?= $row['images']; ?></td>
```

> **error code:** Undefined index: categories; in and Array to string
> conversion in array

I do not know what is required, but I use the following codes when adding a product

```
'categories' => [
    [
        'id' => $_POST['test1'],
    ]
],
$test1 = $_POST['test1'];
```

And woocommerce category and image php code;
[Create a product](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-product)

I don't know how to call these arrays

Comment: The categories is an array and you have to travel them like- `$row['categories'][0]['id']` and similar thing is for images too.

Comment: Only 1 worked well thanks only 1 could work
What should I do if there are two categories in a reputation?

Comment: You need to extract them using `array_column()` or doing a loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support, I will try to find out how it was done